# Rails: get all fields from multiple models by join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is three models:

```
class Swimming::Classschedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :swimming_classtimes ,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classtime',:foreign_key => "classtime_id"  
  attr_accessible :id,:coach_id, :level_id, :note, :classtime_id
end


class Swimming::Classtime < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swimming_classschedules,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classschedule'
  belongs_to :swimming_timeblocks ,:class_name=>'Swimming::Timeblock',:foreign_key => "timeblock_id"    
  attr_accessible :date, :end, :start,:timeblock_id,:id
end


class Swimming::Timeblock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swimming_classtimes,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classtime'
  has_many :swimming_classschedules,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classschedule',:through => :swimming_classtimes
  attr_accessible :name,:id
end
```

And I try to join these three models

```
schedules = Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:swimming_classtimes=>:swimming_timeblocks).select("swimming_classtimes.*,swimming_timeblocks.*,swimming_classschedules.*").where("swimming_classtimes.date >= '2013-06-01' and swimming_classtimes.date <= '2013-06-08' ")
```

Here is the result returned

```
=> [#<Swimming::Classschedule id: 7, coach_id: nil, level_id: nil, note: nil, created_at: "2013-06-08 23:24:31", updated_at: "2013-06-08 23:24:31", lesson_id: 1, classtime_id: 24, lane_id: nil, program_id: nil, classtype_id: nil>]
```

Why it only returned fields from swimming_classschedules. I expected to return all fields from three models

```
"swimming_classtimes.*,swimming_timeblocks.*,swimming_classschedules.*"
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swimming::Classschedule has attributes defined only for its db columns. You can access the other fields using

object[:column_name]

eg:

```
schedules.first[:timeblock_id]
```